# Fire Serverside event from javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008

i have hiddentfield whose value is changing on javascript.

I just wanted to fire serverside event valuechanged event of hiddenfield when its value changed from javascript.

I tried with :

```
__doPostBack('hfLatitude', 'ValueChanged');
```

But giving me error :

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: '__doPostBack' is undefined
```

Is there any other alternative for this?

Please help me.

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using hidden field's value changed event : <asp:HiddenField OnValueChanged="EventHandler" />

Comment: y6es, i am using it, but wants to call it from javascript

Answer (score 4):

In javascript, changes in value to hidden elements don't automatically fire the "onchange" event. So you have to manually trigger your code that is already executing on postback using "GetPostBackEventReference".

So, with a classic javascript approach, your code should look something like in the example below.

In your aspx/ascx file:

```
    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hID" OnValueChanged="hID_ValueChanged" Value="Old Value" />
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="litMessage"></asp:Literal>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClientChage" Text="Change hidden value" OnClientClick="ChangeValue(); return false;" />

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function ChangeValue()
        {
            document.getElementById("<%=hID.ClientID%>").value = "New Value";
            // you have to add the line below, because the last line of the js code at the bottom doesn't work
            fValueChanged();
        }

        function fValueChanged()
        {
            <%=this.Page.GetPostBackEventReference(hID, "")%>;
        }

        // the line below doesn't work, this is why you need to manually trigger the fValueChanged methiod
        // document.getElementById("<%=hID.ClientID%>").onchange = fValueChanged;

    </script>
```

In your cs file:

```
protected void hID_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    litMessage.Text = @"Changed to '" + hID.Value + @"'";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer saved me a headache. However visual studio warned that ```this.Page.GetPostBackEventReference``` is now obsolete and it is better to use ```this.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference```

Answer (score 1):

**First way** is to use [HiddenField.ValueChanged Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield.valuechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

If you want to also watch this varible in Client Side just use this:

```
    $('#hidden_input').change(function() { 
     alert('value changed');
});
```

**Second way** is to assign value to Varible:

```
$('#hidden_input').val('new_value').trigger('change');
```

Comment: but for this do i need to have any jquery file?

Comment: what is val('new_value')?

Comment: I made like this: $('#hfLatitude').val('new_value').trigger('change'); ....giving me error $ is undefined

Comment: You don't have Jquery included.

Comment: sir, with hiddentfield its not allowing me to have onchenge event

Comment: what can be possible alternative then?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and Dirty:

Simply put a asp button on form. Set it `display:none`.

```
<asp:Button id="xyx" runat="server" style="display:none" OnClick="xyx_Click" />
```

On its click event call any server side event.

```
protected void xyx_Click(o,e)
{
   //you server side statements
}
```

To call its from JS use as below:

```
<script>

function myserverside_call()
{
var o = document.getElementById('<%=xyx.ClientID%>');
o.click();
}

function anyotherjsfunc()
{
   //some statements
   myserverside_call();
}
</script>
```

Comment: I have hiddenfield and valuechange event with which its not working